# No transform available between EPSG:2100 and Unknown CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

After upgrading from 3.04 to 3.10 my QGIS projects keep reporting "No transform available between EPSG:2100 and Unknown CRS" although the project settings dictate that EPSG:2100 should be used.
After spending a fair amount of time reading QGIS Github issues and suggestions such as [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36699) I cleaned my installation and moved to the latest ubuntugis version with GDAL 3.1.3 and PROJ 7.1.1 but the issue persists.
[image]

The error message appears whenever I try to use my raster to generate a new 3D view.

Also, whenever a new layer is created (eg a new Visibility Analysis) it gets a different CRS than the project default
[image: Unkown CRS for new Layer]

It feels like something is not initialized correctly but it's been extremely hard to figure out what.

Comment: Is it set properly in `settings / options / CRS  / CRS for layers`?

Comment: @JGH Yes. It is supposed to be. The screenshot I posted is how a new layer is being setup in Unknown CRS instead of the EPSG2100 which is the default for the project and any new layers